# How to make an app start with a lower 'nice' value

Tags: cpu-load, nice

I would like to know how to make a program (Eclipse) always start with a lower 'nice' value.

I tried to manipulate ‘/usr/share/applications/eclipse.desktop’ - with no success.

```
Exec='nice -n -10 eclipse'
```

Here is the solution as described by 'geirha':

**Step 1 - allow user to run nice on eclipse as root:**

EDITOR=nano visudo -f /etc/sudoers.d/local_changes

```
# Last row must always be empty!

# Allow certain users to change 'nice' values
User_Alias NICE_USERS = USER_NAME1, USER_NAME2...
Cmnd_Alias SET_ECLIPSE_NICE = /root/eclips_nice.sh
NICE_USERS ALL = NOPASSWD:SET_ECLIPSE_NICE
```

**Step 2 - create the script that launches eclipse with nice -10:**

nano /root/eclips_nice.sh

```
 #!/bin/bash

 nice -n -10 sudo -H -u "$1" eclipse

 exit
```

chmod u+x /root/eclips_nice.sh

**Step 3 - edit eclipse launcher:**

nano /usr/share/applications/eclipse.desktop

change Exec to:

```
Exec=sh -c 'gksudo -- /root/eclips_nice.sh "$USER"'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the quotes.

```
Exec=nice -n -10 eclipse
```

Edit: though only the root user can set a niceness lower than 0, so

```
Exec=sh -c 'eclipse & gksudo -- renice -n -10 $!'
```

Or maybe better:

```
Exec=sh -c 'exec gksudo -- nice -n -10 sudo -H -u $USER eclipse'
```

Comment: doesn't work, nice is 0

Comment: @Paradiesstaub ah right, only root can set a niceness lower than 0, so you have to renice it afterwards, as root.

Comment: Okay, your solution works for admin users. Now lets remove the pw dialog. I tried all the time to exit '/etc/sudoers.d/' → 'Cmnd_Alias SET_NICE = /usr/bin/nice -n -10 sudo -u tux eclipse'. This works too but only for one user. So maybe you can tell me a way how to remove the pw dialog or I find a generic way using sudoers.d

Comment: @Paradiesstaub For that, write a wrapper script that does `nice -n -10 sudo -H -u "$USER" eclipse`, change the desktop entry to `Exec=gksudo -- thatscript`, and allow the users to run this script as root instead.

Comment: @Paradiesstaub err, I didn't think that through. The USER variable in that script will be root, so `Exec=sh -c 'gksudo -- thatscript "$USER"'` and use "$1" instead of "$USER" in the script.

Comment: This is just so awesome! I know a bit about bash scripts but not that much. Thanks!!!